# Transition on everything except rotate

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to use transition on everything except rotate (on hover arrow needs to me immediately rotated). Here's my css

```
.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: $primaryfont;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;

.btn--arrow {
  background-image: url("/images/icons/arrow-white.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;

  &:hover {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background-image: url("/images/icons/arrow-black.svg");
  }
 }
}
```

When I've used `transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s, transform 0` it canceled all of my transitions. How can I prevent that?

Comment: `0` --> `0s` ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work, tried that aswell.

Comment: Maybe not use 'all' only replace all necessary values for example:
transition: padding 0.3s, color 0.3s

Comment: @Kuci yeah, did that, worked well, thanks!

Comment: Setting it to ```0s'``` as mentioned by @TemaniAfif does work.

Comment: @prettyInPink i didn't for me - it just canceled all my transitions for this element

Comment: @Paweł, looks instantaneous: https://jsfiddle.net/ocra91x4/ but still preserving other transitions, anyway, you got it working :)